# aiohttp terminate web.app_run

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

```py
from aiohttp import web

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', handle),
                web.get('/{name}', handle)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

The above example is from [oficial documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/#server-example).

The question is how can i terminate the `web.run_app(app)` operations with no `KeyBoardInterrupt` (Ctrl+C)?

I am looking something like:

```
await app.shutdown()
await app.cleanup()
```

but i don't know where can i put this code and how can i use it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @atline answer I wrote this code:

```py
import signal
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web_runner import GracefulExit

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import requests
import time

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

async def shutdown(request):
    print("will shutdown now")
    raise GracefulExit()

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/shutdown', shutdown),
                web.get('/', handle),
                web.get('/{name}', handle)])

def init_aiohttp():
    web.run_app(app, host="127.0.0.1", port="8080", ssl_context=None)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    for i in range(0, 1):
        aiohttp = executor.submit(init_aiohttp)

    total_time = 0
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1)
        total_time += 1
        if total_time == 5:
            try:
                requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/shutdown')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        print(total_time)
```

The above code:

1. Starts an `aiohttp` server.
2. Close the server after 5 second (fetching the shutdown url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/shutdown)

Answer (score 1):

From the [source](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/web.py#L518), it looks response for `KeyboardInterrupt` and `GracefulExit`:

```
try:
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
except (GracefulExit, KeyboardInterrupt):  # pragma: no cover
    pass
finally:
    _cancel_tasks({main_task}, loop)
    _cancel_tasks(asyncio.all_tasks(loop), loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
    loop.close()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(None)
```

As you don't want to stop in manual, you could raise `GracefulExit` in your own code, something like next:

**test.py:**

```
import signal
from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web_runner import GracefulExit

async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    return web.Response(text=text)

async def shutdown(request):
    print("will shutdown now")
    raise GracefulExit()

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/shutdown', shutdown),
                web.get('/', handle),
                web.get('/{name}', handle)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

Once you want to close the server, you could send `http://ip:8080/shutdown` to server.

**Additional,** if you want to exit the server directly after receive a request, you may also use `signal.alarm(3)`, then you no need to define a handler with `/shutdown`. This means send a alarm to program after 3 seconds after receive any request (aiohttp internal already register a signal handler with `loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, _raise_graceful_exit)`):

```
async def handle(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    text = "Hello, " + name
    signal.alarm(3)
    return web.Response(text=text)
```

**Anyway,** the way to close the server is either `raise GracefulExit` or `send signal`, but the timing to exit the server depends on your scenario.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Check out mine based on yours.

Comment: @ChrisP If you just want to close the server after 5 seconds? Maybe you could just add `signal.alarm(5)` before `web.run_app(app)`? No `shutdown url` needed I guess.

Comment: First of all i changed the code and works. That's the good news i suppose. Second, i don't want to stop the server after 5 second, but i want to stop the server after a PyQt5 QDialog window close.